# Track MongoDB users operations

Tags: mongodb, monitoring

What is the best way to track operations done on my `MongoDB` instance?
I want to display a graph with the number of user's operations (insert, update, query etc..) done.

I have read about [profiling](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/), but is there a better strategy? How does the `MMS` do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Manager (née MMS) documentation includes a list of the [Database Commands Used by the Monitoring Agent](https://docs.cloud.mongodb.com/reference/monitoring/#database-commands-used-by-the-monitoring-agent).

The main command to start with is [`serverStatus`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/), which includes most metrics specific to a `mongod` instance (as opposed to replica set or sharded cluster information).

You can run this command via a driver and preview the results with the `db.serverStatus()` helper in the `mongo` shell.

Available subsections and output may vary depending on the version and configuration of your MongoDB server.

Interesting sections of serverStatus typically include:

- [opcounters](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#server-status-opcounters): insert, query, update, delete, command, getmore
- [opcounters-repl](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#server-status-opcounters-repl): opcounters that are the result of replicated operations applied on a secondary
- [connections](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#connections): current, available, and total created connections
- [asserts](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/#asserts): number and type of assertions that have been raised since the server started

For more information see:

- [`serverStatus` command description](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/serverStatus/)
- [Server Status Output](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/)